# Combining split data into columns and filter out blanks when importHTML

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

With Google sheets can importHTML be combined with a formula like arrays and filters. I can perform these tasks after using importHTML manually. Array to split data in one cell into three columns and filter to remove blank cells.

I can use macros to perform these tasks or use Automator in Mac.
I have a sneaky feeling this is the limitation of importHTML maybe a solution with AppleScript or JavaScript. Python maybe a easier option.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks looks like it can be achieved ={"Title","Artist";ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(
   QUERY(IMPORTHTML(B1,B2,B3),
     "select Col3"),char(10)),
   "select Col1,Col2 where Col2 is not null and Col1 <> 'Title, Artist'
      order by Col2,Col1 ",0))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `query()` wrapper to filter and aggregate dynamic arrays such as data retrieved with `importhtml()`.

To combine, split and otherwise process dynamic arrays, use an array enabled formula that contains an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) or one of these functions: `arrayformula()`, `filter()`, `sort()`, `sortn()`, `index()`, `query()`, `unique()`, `transpose()`, `indirect()`, `offset()`, `flatten()`, `split()`, `mmult()`, `iferror()`, `ifna()`, `switch()`, `choose()`, `isbetween()`, `importrange()`,  `array_constrain()`, `frequency()`, `growth()`, `linest()`, `logest()`, `minverse()`, `trend()`, `daverage()`, `dcount()`, `dcounta()`, `dget()`, `dmax()`, `dmin()`, `dproduct()`, `dstdev()`, `dstdevp()`, `dsum()`, `dvar()` or `dvarp()`.